# Post-apocalyptic movie about matriarchal society

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

This post-apocalyptic movie was probably made in the 80's.

It plays in a matriarchal society, where men are slaves. I remember only one scene, where the main guy escapes a camp of women (the women are like Amazons) and by accident he falls into a cave (the scenery is similar to Grand Canyon). It turns out that the cave is a long lost, hidden fort, and he is in a control room. He sees monitors and computers, and a recording starts where he sees how the human civilization was before the apocalypse, skyscrapers, and such stuff. I think that before that, nobody knew what happened, and how the old world was at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is **America 3000**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_3000):

> America 3000 is a 1986 post-apocalyptic science-fiction cult film which takes place 900 years in the future in Colorado. Mankind has been reduced to Stone Age conditions and is under the rule of Amazon-like women warriors. The film was directed by David Engelbach, and stars Chuck Wagner, Laurene Landon, and William Wallace.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is it!! Thank you! :)

Comment: Wow, this looks **dreadful**

Comment: Yup, makes you want to download it straight away! :-D

Comment: @Abulafia - I'm still working my way through season 8 of MST3K.

Comment: That movie looks so bad that i have to see it.